# how to copy a file from one server to 2 different severs

Tags: shell-script

I need to copy a file for two different severs using shell script.
I tried to use
Scp usernameip adress and destination path of the folder

Comment: How did you type the command? this should work if the servers run a ssh daemon. To let it work automatically you should make use of ssh keys.

Answer (score 5):

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/338792/scp-a-single-file-to-multiple-locations) you could write a little shell script:

```
for dest in $(<destinations.txt); do
  scp /path/to/the/file_to_copy.txt ${dest}:/remote/path/
done
```

You just need to create `destinations.txt` file where you will fill **in each line** the destination `user@host` , something as follow eg.:

```
root@192.168.1.65
phphil@unix.stackexchange.com
```

Note that the destination path (`/remote/path/`) is hardcoded in the script, it means that this path must exists in both servers. If you prefer to set a dedicated path for each destination, you could edit the script, remove `:/remote/path/` and set it for each of your entry in `destinations.txt`.

Otherwise you could give a look at [parallel-scp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/parallel-scp.1.html)

Comment: Hi lese, can you please elborte the syntax.

Comment: Hi Sindhu, what does it mean?

Comment: am new to shell script so you have mention like dest so in dest i need to provide the ip adrress or file name

Comment: Oh sorry, I got it. The scp is just in its standard form, but the destination ip/name is a variable, filled by entries (content) of destfile.txt using a for cicle. So you don't have to edit "dest" variable, but you need to set the ip addresses of destination servers (or sure, the domain names). I did update the answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 2):

By using RSA you can make a script to send the files without it prompting for your password, your password does not have to be typed into the script.
run on your computer:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
ssh-copy-id loginname@server1Ip
ssh-copy-id loginname@server2Ip
```

inside your script:

```
scp file loginname@server1IP
scp file loginname@server2IP
```

if your login and local user name are the same you can leave out the loginname@ part